# How do I create directories AND subdirectories with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, directory

I have a variable `copyFolderPath` as `c:\images\movies\users\joe\`

I have the following code:

```
If objFSO.FolderExists(copyFolderPath) = False Then
    Wscript.Echo "Creating: " + copyFolderPath
    objFSO.createFolder copyFolderPath
End If
```

The problem is, this only create the `joe` directory if it doesn't exist. I need code that will also create the `users`, `movies`, or `images` directory as well if they don't exist.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [copying folder to another path getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174284/copying-folder-to-another-path-getting-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this function:

```
Sub subCreateFolders(strPath)

   If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
      strPath = strPath & "\"
   End If

   strNewFolder = ""
   Do Until strPath = strNewFolder
      strNewFolder = Left(strPath, InStr(Len(strNewFolder) + 1, strPath, "\"))

      If objFSO.FolderExists(strNewFolder) = False Then
         objFSO.CreateFolder(strNewFolder)
      End If
   Loop
End Sub
```